# How can i view the UI of Elastic Load Balancer 2.1.0,

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, wso2, wso2-stratos

> HI, just now i download  the  Elastic Load Balance 2.1.0 from WSO2 ,It
>   is running on terminal side of Linux ubuntu, but it is not showing the
>   Management console url. If it is not showing url  where can i get UI
>   of  Elastic Load Balance.
>
> i have a  multiple esb server with same configuration.if my a1 server
>   go down that time data load will shift to my a2 server .Is this use of
>   Elasticloadbalance will you explain me about this what is the exactly
>   use of this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no UI component for ELB. Everything has to be done through configuring physical files.

Elastic LoadBalancer 2.1.0 is based on Hazlecast dependent clustering. This has two parts, one is load balancing and the other is elasticity. Load Balancing is simply distributing workload  among a number of endpoints configured in a static or dynamic manner. Elasticity is simply scaling, ie monitoring load on worker nodes and starts or terminates nodes based on need on an IaaS environment.

Not only manages when a node goes down but also depending on load it can spawn new nodes to handle and if the load is low it can kill unwanted instances in an IaaS environment.

Comment: Where can i declare the endpoints either in ESB or ELB, if it is ELB, can you please explain me in detail with simple example.

Comment: You can refer the documentation which explains configuration in detail, http://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB210/Auto-Scaling+Configuration

Comment: @Kanchetianeel , do you know where to see each worker node's status in a ELB architecture ? I mean, how do I know whether a worker node is crashed or alive ? Thanks